# jQuery - when scroll to section.drk change color of logo

Tags: jquery, html, css

when scrolled to the section.drk changes the color of the logo, but only changes in the first section.drk and the rest does not. Can anyone help?

This is my code in jQuery

```
$.hdchng = function () {
  var hubchng = $('.drk');
  var distance = hubchng.offset().top;
    $window = $(window);

  $window.scroll(function () {
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
      $('.part1').addClass('darkmode');
      $('.part2,part4').addClass('greymode');
      $('.mngNv').addClass('menudrk');
    } else {
      $('.part1').removeClass('darkmode');
      $('.part2,part4').removeClass('greymode');
      $('.mngNv').removeClass('menudrk');
    }
  });
};
$.hdchng();
```

and html:

```
<section class="MNGwb drk"> <- it works here
</section>
<section class="MNGex"> <- it works here
</section>
<section class="MNGwb drk"> <- it doesn't work here
</section>
```

Comment: It is because this line: `var distance = hubchng.offset().top;` calculates one distance. You should calculate and consider multiple distances.

Comment: @Aydin4ik Great! Is there a way to make it simple?

Comment: Sure, if you can make a JS snippet and put your HTML (parts 1,2,4 and mngNv), CSS (darkmode, greymode, menudrk) and the above JS there, and include it in your answer, you can get an edit on your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this snippet. You should be able to adjust it to your code. I would need to see the exact code you have in your page to advise anything more detailed.

```js
var hubTopDistances = [];
var hubBtmDistances = [];
var i = 0;

$('section.drk').each(function(i,el) {
  hubTopDistances.push($(el).offset().top);
  hubBtmDistances.push($(el).offset().top + $(el).height());
});

var drkCount = hubTopDistances.length;

var breakpoint = {
 value: 0,
 reference: 'midScrn',
 set: function() {
       var v = calcDistances();
       breakpoint.value = v[breakpoint.reference];
        }
};

$(window).scroll(function () {
  breakpoint.set();
  $('.distanceToTop').text(parseInt(breakpoint.value));
  for (i = 0; i < drkCount; i++) {
   if (breakpoint.value > hubTopDistances[i]) {
     if (breakpoint.value < hubBtmDistances[i]) {
       goDark();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  goLight(); // If the function didn't return at goDark(), means we gotta goLight()
});

function goDark() {
 $('.distanceToTop').addClass('darkmode');
}
function goLight() {
  $('.distanceToTop').removeClass('darkmode');
}
function calcDistances() {
  var scrlTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  return {
      scrlTop: scrlTop,
      midScrn: scrlTop + ($(window).height() / 2),
      scrnBtm: scrlTop + $(window).height()
  }
}
```

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
}
.distanceToTop {
  position:fixed;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  text-align:right;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.layout {
  position:relative;
}
.darkmode {
  background-color: navy;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout">
  <div class="distanceToTop">

  </div>
  <section class="MNGwb drk"> Section 1
  </section>
  <section class="MNGex"> Section 2
  </section>
  <section class="MNGwb drk"> Section 3
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include your whole HTML, I added a few divs and some CSS just to demonstrate.  Your code basically works. You just needed to add the dot to your selector for `.part4`.

```js
$.hdchng = function () {
  var hubchng = $('.drk');
  var distance = hubchng.offset().top;
    $window = $(window);
  
  $window.scroll(function () {
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
      $('.part1').addClass('darkmode');
      $('.part2, .part4').addClass('greymode');
      $('.mngNv').addClass('menudrk');
    } else {
      $('.part1').removeClass('darkmode');
      $('.part2, .part4').removeClass('greymode');
      $('.mngNv').removeClass('menudrk');
    }
  });
};
$.hdchng();
```

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 1em;
}
.part1, .part2, .part4 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.part1 {
  left: 0;
}
.part2 {
  left: 120px;
}
.part4 {
  left: 240px;
}
.darkmode {
  background-color: #333;
}
.greymode {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="part1"></div>
<div class="part2"></div>
<div class="part4"></div>
<section class="MNGwb drk"> <!-- it works here -->
</section>
<section class="MNGex"> <!-- it works here -->
</section>
<section class="MNGwb drk"> <!-- it doesn't work here -->
</section>
```

Comment: but it only works in the second section! from there it goes dark